# Regex.Escape - Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll in C#

Tags: c#, regex, c#-8.0

I have Regex to match input string,however when the input string is null I get the below error

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll

This is how my method looks like

```
public async Task<PagedResult<Transaction>> Find(FindTransactionQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
            
    var recipientFirstNameFilter = 
BuildFilterDefinition(Builders<Transaction>.Filter.Regex(_ => _.Recipient.FirstName, new($"/.*{ Regex.Escape(query.RecipientFirstName)}.*/i")), query.RecipientFirstName);

    var senderFirstNameFilter = 
BuildFilterDefinition(Builders<Transaction>.Filter.Regex(_ => _.Sender.FirstName, new($"/.*{Regex.Escape(query.SenderFirstName)}.*/i")), query.SenderFirstName);

    //& so on
}

    private static FilterDefinition<Transaction> BuildFilterDefinition(FilterDefinition<Transaction> transactionFilter, string searchText) =>
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText)
                ? Builders<Transaction>.Filter.Empty
                : transactionFilter;
```

I tried to do with the conditional operator as below, but not allowed:

```
    var recipientFirstNameFilter = BuildFilterDefinition(Builders<Transaction>.Filter.Regex(_ => _.Recipient.FirstName, 
    //here
    new($"/.*{query.RecipientFirstName!= null ? Regex.Escape(query.RecipientFirstName) :query.RecipientFirstName}.*/i")), query.RecipientFirstName);
```

Yes one solution is adding one more variable *& checking the null but introducing an extra variable for this doesn't appeal much.

Is there something similar I can do like !?? (Not Null) & then build Regex?

Thanks!

Comment: Wrap ternary operator in `(..)`: `new($"/.*{(query.RecipientFirstName!= null ? Regex.Escape(query.RecipientFirstName) :query.RecipientFirstName)}.*/i")}, query.RecipientFirstName);`. Please, note that `:` in the *string interpolation* means *format specification* and we have a confict; that's why we have to wrap in `(..)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using *string interpolation*, `:` means *format*:

```
// Here we want 4 digits after decimal point
string demo = $"{Math.PI:f4}";
```

that's why naked *ternary operator* within string interpolation *doesn't compile*:

```
// Compile time error
string demo = $"{Math.PI > 3 ? 'T' : 'F'}";
```

.Net complains for wrong format (here  `'F'`) specification. The solution is to use `(...)`

```
// Now it's correct
string demo = $"{(Math.PI > 3 ? 'T' : 'F')}";
```

In your case

```
new($"/.*{(query.RecipientFirstName!= null ? Regex.Escape(query.RecipientFirstName) : "")}.*/i")), query.RecipientFirstName);
```

or (if we check for `null` within `Regex.Escape` with a help of `??`):

```
new($"/.*{Regex.Escape(query?.RecipientFirstName ?? "")}.*/i")), query.RecipientFirstName);
```

Comment: Wondering, if there is something like !?? (Not Null Colleasing Operator)

Comment: @Kgn-web: no, we have just `??` operator. But you can try something like `Regex.Escape(query?.RecipientFirstName ?? "")` it will be either escaped name or empty string